# Como parar uma aplicação windows forms até que um formulário seja fechado?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Quero que quando o Form1 seja aberto, o programa todo pare, e só volte quando ele for fechado. Como posso fazer isso?

Código que abre o Form1:

```
if (x == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para "bloquear" a aplicação enquanto aguarda o resultado de `Form1`, troque o `.Show` por `.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, até funcionou, mas é que dentro do `Form1.cs`, tenho uma função que atribui alguns valores dentro de um comboBox, e quando eu abro com o `f1.ShowDialog()` ele não executa isso.

Comment: essa função está sendo executada em qual momento ? utilize o evento Load do Form1

Comment: Sim, está no load.

Comment: Se puder, poste o código do Form

Comment: Este é o código inteiro: https://gist.github.com/ceifa/36c0771bc0757ec954118493ffd56a07

Comment: e sem o ShowDialog funciona ?

Comment: Sim, se eu coloco pra ele ser o primeiro form a inicializar, ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: então você não altera somente o ShowDialog para Show, altera mais algo no código... ?

Comment: Não. Altero nada.

Comment: Coloque um point break no código e confere se os valores das variáveis Skins.x não estão vazios

Comment: Não, não estão vazios, como eu disse, se eu colocar para ser o primeiro form a iniciar, tudo funciona perfeitamente.